# Custom Background effect's images for Teams Meetings Tips

Tags: office365, ms-office, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

Many won't waiting for Teams Mai Update to be able to change Background effects images,
So this is the trick to do it now :

Run to AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds\Uploads Folder and just copy in your.png file.

Comment: works great, thanks!

Comment: Amazing...This works, Btw There is option too Apply Background Effect while running in Team Meeting.